# loading large data fails

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I have large amount of data that needs to be fetched from postgres. 
The data amount to around 200000.

The sql query is a set of statements with union and results in this large amount of data.

I am using c#.net to fetch this data. I have tried with both Npgsql as well as dapper.net but the result I receive using this is just about 50000. I am not sure why it does not fetches the entire data using .net whereas if I run the same query it returns all the data.

I am just using simple:

```
_db.Query<MyModel>(query).Count()
```

Do we need to do something extra to handle such large data.

Thanks

Comment: `.Count()` is just returning an int of the count of the data - as per "select count * from MyModel" would be doing

Comment: Do a database trace, I bet your manual query is not the same as what you pass to the ORM.

Comment: Looks like my execution plan was being cached, when I run with RECOMPILE option it was fine. Have to look at why did it happened. Thanks for your inputs.